# the value of the promise is returned as an [object, object] in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a navigation in react:

```
    const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        LoginStack: LoginStack,
        HomeStack: DrawerStack
    },
    {
        headerMode: "none",
        initialRouteName: "LoginStack"  -------------> value default
    }
    );
```

According to the value stored in my localstorage I want to redirect the route to Login or Home

```
    const getSessionPrevious = async () => {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
        if (value !== null) {
        return "HomeStack";
        } else {
        return "LoginStack";
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return "LoginStack";
    }
    };
```

the function `"getSessionPrevious()"` is responsible for returning the value in localstorage, if the token exists the route will be: `"HomeStack"` otherwise it will be `"LoginStack"`

if I put for example:

```
    initialRouteName: 1+1==2?'LoginStack':'HomeStack"
```

it works

But I am getting this error putting my function.

```
    const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        LoginStack: LoginStack,
        HomeStack: DrawerStack
    },
    {
        headerMode: "none",
```

I added `getSessionPrevious()`

```
        initialRouteName: getSessionPrevious()
    }
    );
```

[image]

this is my full code:

What am I doing wrong

```
    import React from "react";
    import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

    import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
    import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
    import { createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation-drawer";
    import SideBar from "../components/SideBar/SideBar";
    import LoginScreen from "../screens/Login/Login";
    import HomeScreen from "../screens/Home/Home";
    import ContainerDetailScreen from "../screens/ContainerDetail/ContainerDetail";
    import { STYLES } from "../styles/Styles";


    const getSessionPrevious = async () => {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
        if (value !== null) {
        return "HomeStack";
        } else {
        return "LoginStack";
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return "LoginStack";
    }
    };


    const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        LoginStack: LoginStack,
        HomeStack: DrawerStack
    },
    {
        headerMode: "none",
        initialRouteName: getSessionPrevious()
    }
    );

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);
    export default AppContainer;
```

Comment: `getSessionPrevious` returns a `Promise`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Oh, I'm new to this, but then what should I do to get the chain I need back?

Comment: At some point, you need to handle the async nature of JS, it's hard to say. It looks like it depends on your whole app flow. But you'll need to `await` the promise if you want its value.

Comment: @EmileBergeron What do you mean? I have a specific problem that I do not know how to solve, I have worked with promises, I have tried many things, but I have this blocker, so I asked this question, I do not know how to solve it. You tell me that this returns a promise, but I don't know how to return the value I need. Sure if I managed to solve it will increase my knowledge

Comment: Since it's a login flow, show the home page by default (empty as no data is loaded yet) and redirect to the login page later if there's no token or if you get a 401 error while fetching data.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I don't have a default homepage. I just have navigation land on Home or Login. This is my current flow, and promptly I need to solve my problem that I know you understand.

Comment: My recommandation is to choose one page (say login) and handle the async validation there (like in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle function). It won't slow the app initialization process like you're trying to do with async storage and will show the login page briefly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203335/discussion-between-yavg-and-emile-bergeron).

Comment: @EmileBergeron can you start the chat with me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do in your case is just show the login page by default, and fetch the token from the local storage while the loading spinner is shown.

Here's a super simple example:

```
const Login = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("token").then(
      token => {
        if (token) {
          // Redirect to the home page if the token is available
          Router.push("/home");
        } else {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      },
      () => {
        // failed?
        setLoading(false);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      {loading ? (
        <div>loading</div>
      ) : (
        <div className="login-form">
          Username: <input />
          Password: <input />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

Trying to do async operations in the app bootstrap phase will lead you to async module imports which is unnecessarily complex for your use-case.